# Possible Duplicate question & answer paradox?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-answers, duplicate-answers

I curated an answer for one of the questions,

[can't access mysql from command line mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195418/cant-access-mysql-from-command-line-mac)

and later found since there was similar question I posted same answer

[MySQL command line '-bash command not found'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391778/mysql-command-line-bash-command-not-found)

Now I understand moderator deleted answer flagging as duplicate but turns out he did it on both and commented I should flag question duplicate pointing to other. Which I did.

But how do I get one of the answer undeleted? It's paradox since I can't undelete either answers?

Comment: You can undelete-vote one answer.

Comment: I did. It says A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted

Comment: Then flag it and explain what happened and refer to this question here. Sometimes mods make mistakes.

Comment: Thanks @GertArnold. I flagged it & even tweeted mod about it.

Comment: You posted the same answer **three** times - two were deleted. The moderator even left you an informative comment: "Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question*." -- have you followed that advice?

Answer (score 3):

I've undeleted one post, deleted the other.

In future, use a single flag on the post to ask us to do something. I tend to ignore tweets, as they rarely include enough context to allow me to follow up, nor can other moderators see those and handle your case.

Also, take into account it is a weekend and even moderators occasionally do other things not related to Stack Overflow. Not all flags require handling *right now*.

Comment: Great & sounds good. I understand mods are busy. I wasn't really aware i was flagging more than once. There wasn't proper feedback except later realising decrease in flag count. Sorry if it was too much of a trouble didn't mean to pester yeah.